# Oracle10g Connection String Timeout

Tags: oracle, web-config, oracle10g, connection-string

How do I go about setting a correct timeout in an Oracle 10g connection string?

Right now I have:

```
 <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DBNAME;User ID=someUser;Password=somePassword;Unicode=True; Connection Timeout=60"
  providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

Whenever it encounters this connection string, especially my GridView, it says that 'Connection Timeout' is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

`Connection Timeout` is not a valid parameter with this provider.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectionstring.aspx) what parameters are valid for Microsoft provider.

This parameter is valid for `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection` from  Oracle.DataAccess.dll provided by Oracle. This is currently a recommended provider because `System.Data.OracleClient` namespace is deprecated and will be removed from future versions of .NET based on [this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.100%29)